# Convert scm configuration to pipeline in Jenkinsfile

Tags: xml, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have this xml configuration and I want to write it in Jenkinsfile, how can I do that
I tried to use other plugins but they does not give me a correct conversion. Can any one help

```
<scm class="hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM" plugin="git@4.1.1">
    <configVersion>2</configVersion>
    <userRemoteConfigs>
        <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
            <name>fid</name>
            <url>git@gitlab.com:urw-group/apps/digital_marketing-commercial_centers/fid/loyalty-server.git</url>
            <credentialsId>jenkins-gitlab-ssh-key</credentialsId>
        </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
        <hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
            <name>fid-ghost</name>
            <url>git@gitlab.com:urw-group/apps/digital_marketing-commercial_centers/fid/Ghosts-packages/staging.git</url>
            <credentialsId>jenkins-gitlab-ssh-key</credentialsId>
        </hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig>
    </userRemoteConfigs>
    <branches>
        <hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
            <name>fid-ghost/master</name>
        </hudson.plugins.git.BranchSpec>
    </branches>
    <doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>false</doGenerateSubmoduleConfigurations>
    <submoduleCfg class="list"/>
    <extensions/>
</scm>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the **Pipeline Syntax Generator**, its available in `<Your_Jenkins_URL>/job/<Your_Pipeline_Job_Name>/pipeline-syntax/`.
In the generator use **checkout** as the stage, choose Git and fill your details, then click on the **Generate Pipeline Script** and you will get the code you need.
It will look like:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: 'fid-ghost/master']],
          userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: 'jenkins-gitlab-ssh-key', url: 'git@gitlab.com:urw-group/apps/digital_marketing-commercial_centers/fid/loyalty-server.git'],
                              [credentialsId: 'jenkins-gitlab-ssh-key', url: 'git@gitlab.com:urw-group/apps/digital_marketing-commercial_centers/fid/Ghosts-packages/staging.git']]
])
```

It can be used bot in scripted and in declarative pipelines.